# One one Functions

Tags: functions

Let $ f(x)$ & $g(x)$ be two functions. 
If $g(f(x))$ is one-one, then $f(x)$ must be one-one but $g(x)$ need not be. 
Why?

My thoughts: 
We can have a case as follows: when I put in two different values into $f(x)$, I get two different output. However, since $g(x)$ isn't one-one, it can give same output for *those* two values, making the composite function many-one. So, $g(x)$ should be one-one too.

Comment: You should work through some arbitrary examples where the domains and codomains of $f$ and $g$ have two, three or four points in different combinations, to really see what happens. What you see there generalizes well in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the domain of $g$ may be larger than the range of $f$. Say $g = \log \vert x \vert$ and $f = e^x$. $g$ is not one-to-one because it gives the same  value for every $x$ as it does for $-x$, but $g(f(x)) = x$ is one-to-one because the range of $f$ is only positive numbers. You are correct that there are cases where $g$ and $f$ need both be one-one; for instance when every input to $g$ is given as an output by $f$.

Comment: Aah. "Need not be"! It means we can have special cases where things can workout without g(x) being one-one.

Comment: That's right! "need not be" means something like "it'd be nice if it were true, but we can work around it"

Answer (score 1):

Let the domain of $f$ be a singleton.

Then also the domain of $g\circ f$ is a singleton and consequently both functions are injective.

Function $g$ is free to show any behaviour you want.

Comment: But, it can't be generalized. Can it be? Please go through Tindal's answer to the question. And give your views.

Comment: It can be generalized like this: let $f$ be injective and let $g$ be injective on the image of $f$. Then $g\circ f$ is injective. However $g$ is free to show any behaviour you want on the elements of its domain that do not belong to the image of $f$. Exactly as stated by Andrew Tindall. If such elements do not exist then $f$ is bijective. From $f$ bijective and $g\circ f$ injective you are allowed to conclude that $g$ is injective.

Comment: But I guess, we can construct cases where g(x) must show one-to-one behaviour. So, I understand that this idea of free behaviour exists with conditions. At least that is what I understand.

Comment: The **only** condition on free behaviour of $g$ in this context is that it occurs not on the image of $f$.